# Can't understand trivial discrete logarithm problem for $Z_{11}$

Tags: discrete-logarithms

I have a seemingly trivial problem with description:

> Find all discrete logarithms of base 2 of all non-zero elements in
>   $Z_{11}$ field.

I'm basing my learning on the notes I managed to grab from other groups and for that problem, there's a solution with only 5 $dlog$'s calculated, namely $dlog_2 1, dlog_2 2, dlog_2 10, dlog_2 7, dlog_2 3$. What I don't get is why are all the other elements of $Z_{11}$ ignored? 2 is a generator of the field so for different values of $i$ you could derive such $2^i$ that it yields numbers from $1$ to $10$. Why don't we calculate the $dlog$'s of all such numbers but only half of them? Or is there  mistake in the answer?

Comment: Without seeing whatever it is you are looking at, it is impossible to tell why someone asked for all the logs and only calculated half of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x\cdot y \equiv 1 \mod p$, then $$
  \underbrace{\textrm{dlog}_2 x}_{=u} + \underbrace{\textrm{dlog}_2 y}_{=v} \equiv 0 \mod (p-1)
$$
because if $2^u \equiv x, 2^v \equiv y$ then $x\cdot y \equiv 2^{u+v} \equiv 1$ if $u + v \mid 10$ (this follows from fermat's little theorem). Over $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ you have $$\begin{eqnarray}
  1 &\cdot& 1 &\equiv& 1 \\
  2 &\cdot& 6 &\equiv& 1 \\
  3 &\cdot& 4 &\equiv& 1 \\
  5 &\cdot& 9 &\equiv& 1 \\
  7 &\cdot& 8 &\equiv& 1 \\
  10 &\cdot& 10 &\equiv& 1
\end{eqnarray}$$
meaning that the discrete $2$-logarithmns of $1,2,3,5,7,10$ suffice to easily express the others. Why your list is missing $\textrm{dlog}_2 5$, I don't know.

Comment: After talking with the notes owner, it turns out they were just given a few examples instead of writing out all the possibilities. Still, I'm accepting this answer because it gives a really interesting insight on how this (or very similar) writing can actually make sense. Thank you :)